# stacked barplot with data arranged by depth

Tags: r, csv, bar-chart, stackedbarseries

I'm trying to plot elemental data that is organized by rows. In other words:

```
Ba   
411.14
183.48
395.92
499.09
747.03
456.42
408.43
524.39
388.14
486.71
488.95
510.93
522.05
730.26
494.24
323.76
652.33
304.03
544.69
378.48
967.14
981.45
1002.67



SY-01 5ft
SY-01 16ft
SY-01 28ft
SY-02 7ft
SY-02 16ft
SY-02 22ft
SY-02 26ft
SY-03 6ft
sy-04 29ft
sy-05 3ft
sy-05 16ft
sy-05 23 ft
sy-06 3 ft
sy-06 18ft
sy-06 28 ft
sy-07 3ft
sy-07 15 ft
sy-07 18 ft
sy-08 21ft
sy-08 25 ft
std
std
2780 std
```

Where each subsequent row is a different depth. Also, these are values collected at several wells so the data above is Barium concentration at varying depths and different wells. I've been trying to construct a stacked barplot to no avail--I've looked at other posts but my data is set up differently so I was unable to find a solution. The data is in a csv format and I got R to correctly read the file and plot the data but I need to figure out how to stack the data according to the well location so that the plot illustrates a bar for each well and is stacked with the depth. Thanks.

Comment: this seems incomplete data to me, if this is barium conc, where is depth and well id or something? and also do you want this depth in range, like 100-200, 200-300 etc and

Comment: Sorry about that Ananta. I just included that information.